# How to add a column from a file to the last column of another file using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to add the second column of `file2` to `file1`, that contains a number an unknown number of columns, so becoming the last column of `file1`.
In this aim, I tried to create a `file3` composed by pasting a `file1` and only the second column of `file2`:

`file1`:

```
col11  col12  col13  ...  col1n
```

`file2`:

```
col21  col22  col23  ...  col2m
```

new `file1` or `file3`:

```
col11 col12  ...  col1n  col22
```

I'm using the command:

```
awk '{ print $0 > "file3"; getline<"file2"; print $2 > "file3" }' file1 &
```

but the arguments of the col22 instead of forming the last column of the new file will go on a new line.

Someone can help me to find and correct the error or also in finding a more effective solution?
My operating system is fedora12.

Comment: To repaire you script just change first `print` to `printf "%s",`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{f1 = $0; getline<"file2"; print f1, $2}' < file1 > file3
```

The output file will have the same number of lines as `file1`, so the last column will be empty for the last lines if `file2` is shorter, and the last values in `file2` will be ignored if it's longer.

Alternatively, as suggested by Costas:

```
awk '{getline f1 <"file1" ; print f1,$2}' < file2 > file3
```

That time though, `file3` will have the same number of lines as `file2`. That means the ordering of columns will be affected if `file2` is longer than `file1`.

With:

```
awk '{print $2}' < file2 | paste file1 - > file3
```

`file3` will have the same number of lines as the biggest of `file1` and `file2`. No data will be discarded, but as above, if `file2` is longer than `file1`, the last lines in `file3` will have `file2`'s data in the first/second column.

Comment: What do you think to make script shorter a little `awk '{getline f1 <"file1" ; print f1,$2}' < file2 > file3`

Comment: @Costas, yes, that works too and looks nicer. There would be a difference though if file1 and file2 don't have the same number of lines.

Comment: Who knows what file (1 or 2) is have more lines?

Comment: file1 and file2 have the same number of lines.

Comment: All the solutions you've proposed work. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next}{print $0,a[FNR]}' file2 file1
col11 col12 col13 ... col1n col22
```

The `{a[NR]=$2;next}` part will be executed only for first file in the list (`file2`), and when `awk` processes the second file (`file1`) we print the whole line of `file1` and add table element `a[FNR]` which holds value of second field of `file2`.

Comment: BTW, you can perform this task also with `paste` and `cut` tools: `paste -d' ' file1 <(cut -d' ' -f2 file2)`

Comment: I suspect the OP's files have more than one line though.